# backbone operator in error when using model.set()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Everything just make sense I don't know what's wrong with my set() helper method, I saw error in the console when i run it.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    age: 30,
    occupation: 'fireman'
  },
  validate: function(attrs) {
    console.log(attrs);
  },
  work: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' is working';
  }
})

var p = new Person({name:'John'});
//p.set('occupation','software developer'); why this has error?
console.log(p.toJSON())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hsnbxe3/

Comment: `p.set` asks for an object, not just two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware, that you linked Backbone.js 0.3.3 in your example? (Today it is version 1.3.3)

Back then, it was not possible to use the .set(key, value) pattern but only to set values by pushing an object as the first parameter.

```
model.set(obj, options)
```

with `obj` an object with the updated attributes or a Backbone model object.

Here use:

```
p.set({"occupation":"software developer"});
```

Comment: any clue why is it so?

Comment: @Sandy you have 2 versions of underscore imported, the latter after backbone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8L54y6by/1/ - i fixed your wrong embedding of the external libs -- there is no error

Comment: so p.set('age',20) is a valid method?

Comment: what is my mistake just now?

Comment: in 1.3.3: yes.
in 0.3.3: no - you should use `p.set({age, 20});` instead.

Comment: *small fix: `p.set({ age: 20 });`

Answer (score 0):

```
p.set({"occupation":"software developer"});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.